# How to send Push with different data for each token in Firebase?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

There is such a code, but it sends a single message to all the tokens specified in the array (1000 tokens). You need to add a personal parameter for each token somewhere to track the unique click - from whom it comes and so on. For example, in click_action. But again, if you add a parameter there, the link in this form will be sent to everyone. Sending one message for each user is not an option, of course.

```
'registration_ids' => $tokens,
'data' => array(
        'title' => 'Title',
        'body' => 'Message',
        'icon' => 'icon.png',
        'image' => 'image.png',
        'click_action' => 'https://site.ru'
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no (mail merge like) customization for each recipient within a single API call. Each call to the FCM API to send a message, sends precisely the message you pass in that call to the topics/tokens you target in that call.

If you want recipients to receive a different message, you will need to perform one API call for each message.

You say:

> Sending one message for each user is not an option

Calling the API fo each unique message is precisely the only option. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be, as it's what all apps using FCM do if they want to deliver personalized content.